# How to set permissions when running VS Code on a Chromebook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, permissions, chromebook

[image]

I'm trying to install Visual Studio Code on a Chromebook.
It seems to have installed normally and I can open the template files that I need.

However, when I try and create a new file I get this permission denied error.

I've tried searching online for help setting permissions so VS Code can access certain Chromebook directories, but can't find the help I need. I've tried creating the new file in both the 'Downloads' directory, and in the 'Google Drive' directory but I get the same error.
I am following along with a coding course in Udemy but the video doesn't show this error occuring.

Comment: Read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your image of text into actual text. Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: If you get further information in any output logs (`View > Output`), please shared those as well (as formatted text and not as images of text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target folder is mounted read-only for installation.
[image]

Right-click on Downloads and select “Share with Linux”.
[image]

A file was created in the target folder.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't realize you could set permissions that way on a Chromebook, it was very easy in the end.